# How to get my excel sheet to copy data to another sheet at the end of each month?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that contains a few numbers. I have another sheet that has the month names in one column. I need to copy the data in sheet 1 sheet to sheet 2 at the end of each month in the corresponding cell. Is there a way to do it?

Right now the data is manually being copy-pasted at the end of each month.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See the [guide on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . If you know some basic Javascript, check out the Google Apps Script's [basic documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) for everything you need to know to start automating stuff like this (you can set this sort of importing to be done on a timed trigger). You might also be able to simply use, for example, `IMPORTRANGE()`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Sheets Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script) to learn the basics of the API. Pay attention to the `rangeName` and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) functions as they will be, with [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to write the data, the only methods you will need to do this.

You have to use `getValues()` to get the data from Sheet1 and write it with `setValues()` to Sheet2. Once you have the script working, create a trigger to execute it once a month:

You will find the option in Edit > Current project's triggers > Add Trigger. In `Select event source` choose `Time-driven` and there you can select the `Month timer` to execute every 30th or 1st day of the month.

If you have any issue with the code, please edit your question with what you tried and we will gladly help you.